# How to answer the question from Calculus by Michael Spivak Chapter 10 Problem 15

Tags: calculus

> If $f + g$  is differentiable at $a$, are $f$ and $g$ necessarily differentiable at $a$?
>
> If $f*g$ and $f$ are differentiable at $a$, what conditions on $f$ imply that $g$ is
>   differentiable at $a$?

I only know for the second question that if $f(a)≠0$ then $g$ is differentiable at $a$

For the first one I guess I have to give a counterexample, but I do not know how to.

Comment: 1) I think not. 

If we imagine a function which is diffentiable nowhere $f$ and take $g=-f$ then $f+g=0$ is certainly differentiable. 

2) I think none. 

 If $f$ and $g-f$ are differentiable at $a$ then isn't $f+(g-f)=g$ also differentiable at $a$?

Comment: Thanks for 1)!
I corrected the 2), It was a multiplication!

Comment: Ok. Multiplication may have some nuance. But I am coming to the same conclusion as you: $f(a)=0$ can mess it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) I think not.

If we imagine a function which is diffentiable nowhere $f$ and take $g=-f$ then $f+g=0$ is certainly differentiable.

To see this consider $f(x)=|x|$ and $g(x)=-f(x)$. Neither function is differentiable at $a=0$ but $f(x)+g(x)=0$ which is differentiable everywhere.

2)  You're right. We can use an argument invoking product rule.

$$(f(x)g(x))' =f'(x)g(x)+g'(x)f(x)$$ So then solving for $g'(x)$ which may or may not exist...

$g'(x)= \frac{(f(x)g(x))'-f'(x)g(x)}{f(x)}$

What's the problem? $g'(x)$ must exist! We can define it in terms of things we know exist. We just need to be careful not to divide by zero...

Answer (score 0):

First question is already answered. For the second one consider $h=fg$, then $g(x)=\frac{h(x)}{f(x)}$, for every $x$ such that $f(x)\neq0$. Since $h$ and $f$ are differentiable at $a$, you just need to ask that $f(a)\neq 0$ to conclude that $g$ is differentiable at $0$.